# Swift Dictionary default value

Tags: swift, dictionary

A pattern I've gotten used to with Python's defaultdicts is a dictionary that returns a default value if the value for a given key has not been explicitly set. Trying to do this in Swift is a little verbose.

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, Array<Int>>()
let key = "foo"
var value: Array<Int>! = dict[key]
if value == nil {
    value = Array<Int>()
    dict[key] = value
}
```

I realize I can make a class that does this, but then the actual Dictionary has to be accessed through a property to use any of the other normal Dictionary methods

```
class DefaultDictionary<A: Hashable, B> {
    let defaultFunc: () -> B
    var dict = Dictionary<A, B>()

    init(defaultFunc: () -> B) {
        self.defaultFunc = defaultFunc
    }
    subscript(key: A) -> B {
        get {
            var value: B! = dict[key]
            if value == nil {
                value = defaultFunc()
                dict[key] = value
            }
            return value
        }
        set {
            dict[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: you can just use the nil-coalescing operator `??`, like this: `var value: Array<Int> = dict[key] ?? []`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant That will assign the desired value to the variable, but will not update the Dictionary

Comment: then write `dict[key] = dict[key] ?? []`, and you can force-unwrap `dict[key]` afterwards.

Comment: Couldn't you make `DefaultDictionary` a subclass of `Dictionary` and inherit all the methods of the superclass?

Comment: @martineau: Dictionary is a struct and cannot be subclassed.

Comment: In that case it might be worthwhile to wrap the `Dictionary` struct in a class (and then derive your subclass from that).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Swift 2 you can achieve something similar to python's version with an extension of `Dictionary`:

```
// Values which can provide a default instance
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

extension Dictionary where Value: Initializable {
    // using key as external name to make it unambiguous from the standard subscript
    subscript(key key: Key) -> Value {
        mutating get { return self[key, or: Value()] }
        set { self[key] = newValue }
    }
}

// this can also be used in Swift 1.x
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(key: Key, or def: Value) -> Value {
        mutating get {
            return self[key] ?? {
                // assign default value if self[key] is nil
                self[key] = def
                return def
            }()
        }
        set { self[key] = newValue }
    }
}
```

The closure after the `??` is used for classes since they don't propagate their value mutation (only "pointer mutation"; reference types).

The dictionaries have to be mutable (`var`) in order to use those subscripts:

```
// Make Int Initializable. Int() == 0
extension Int: Initializable {}

var dict = [Int: Int]()
dict[1, or: 0]++
dict[key: 2]++

// if Value is not Initializable
var dict = [Int: Double]()
dict[1, or: 0.0]
```

Answer (score 50):

This changed in Swift 4, and there's now a way to read a key's value or provide a default value if the key isn't present. For example:

```
let person = ["name": "Taylor", "city": "Nashville"]
let name = person["name", default: "Anonymous"]
```

This is particularly useful when modifying dictionary values, because you can write code like this:

```
var favoriteTVShows = ["Red Dwarf", "Blackadder", "Fawlty Towers", "Red Dwarf"]
var favoriteCounts = [String: Int]()

for show in favoriteTVShows {
    favoriteCounts[show, default: 0] += 1
}
```

I covered this change and others in my article [What's new in Swift 4](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift4).

Comment: That's good to know, but it doesn't quite accomplish the same thing. With the defaultdict-like approach, you can declare the default value once, which is nice. With this approach, it looks like you have to pass the default value in every time you read from the dictionary.

Comment: @alexp , While it looks like you have to pass the the default value in each time, the parameter for `default` is declared as @autoclosure, which creates an implicit closure around the statement supplied as the default argument, thus ensuring that it only gets evaluated/passed when the key is not present. So it's more like defaultdict than realized at first.

Comment: The autoclosure is good but the real issue with this is the dictionary doesn't retain the default value. It works in the example shown because it is also setting the value with `+=`, but in other circumstances it can be totally ineffective.

Comment: This does not always work. Iam running xcode 13.0 and ran the exact code in your article only to return nil as the answer. To reiterate: I ran the following
"
let favoriteIceCream = [
    "Paul": "Chocolate",
    "Sophie": "Vanilla"
]

favoriteIceCream["Paul"]
favoriteIceCream["Charlotte", default: "Unknown"]

print(favoriteIceCream["Charlotte"])
"

My original problem is this:
"
var prayer = [
    "fajr"  :   "05:30",
    "asr"   :   "16:00",
    "magrib":   "17:30",
    "jumma" :   "19:00",
]
prayer["isha", default: "dopdo"]
"
No vote down out of respect :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding defaultdict in Python, I don't see how nil coalescing wouldn't work for you. Let's say you had a dictionary of type `[Int:Int]`, and you wanted it to return 0 by default. With nil coalescing it looks like this:

```
let dict = [1:10, 2:8, 3:64]
let valueForKey = dict[4] ?? 0
```

You mentioned in a comment that that wouldn't work because it wouldn't update the dictionary. I don't understand the problem, though: why would you need to update the dictionary if you knew that every instance of nil would be replaced by your default? Maybe I'm missing something here but it seems like defaults and nil coalescing are (in practice) the same.

[You *can* change the syntax a little, if it makes things more clear](https://twitter.com/AirspeedSwift/status/626701244455895044):

```
extension Dictionary {
  subscript(key: Key, or r: Value) -> Value {
    get { return self[key] ?? r }
    set { self[key] = newValue }
  }
}
```

In this case, the example above could be written like this:

```
let dict = [1:10, 2:8, 3:64]
let valueForKey = dict[4, or: 0]
```

In this case, mutating methods can work on the keys, like this:

```
var dict = [2: 8, 3: 64, 1: 10]
dict[2, or: 0]++
dict // [2: 9, 3: 64, 1: 10]
dict[4, or: 0]++
dict // [2: 9, 3: 64, 1: 10, 4: 1]
```

Comment: It doesn't work if `Value` is a `class` type, because reference types don't propagate its mutations to the owner.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you. [But when I implemented the above with a class it seemed to work fine](http://swiftstub.com/229839678/?v=beta).

Comment: And yeah it is basically a question of syntax. In python it's nice that i can say x = collections.defaultdict(list) and then do x["foo"].append("bar") without caring about whether x["foo"] has been initialized yet. Having to repeat the default value every time is not super convenient.

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense. Yeah, unfortunately there's probably no easy way to do what you're looking for, then. The above method is probably the most "Swifty".

Comment: @oisdk see [the different behavior between `class` and `struct`](http://swiftstub.com/566043165/?v=beta)

Answer (score 0):

This extension is similar to the `default` subscript in Swift 4, with the difference that it will actually store the default value in the dictionary.
(It's also similar to QByte's answer, with the difference that it uses an autoclosure to prevent accessing the default when not needed).

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(key: Key, setDefault defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> Value) -> Value {
        mutating get {
            return self[key] ?? {
                let value = defaultValue()
                self[key] = value
                return value
            }()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that no setter is defined for the subscript as the standard `default` subscript already fulfills this purpose.

Example:

```
var items = [String: ComplexItem]()

let item1 = items["milk", setDefault: ComplexItem()]
let item2 = items["milk", setDefault: ComplexItem()]
```

Here the `ComplexItem` is only created once because the dictionary retained it after the first access.