# Does the Swift standard Dictionary have a get-or-set function?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift-dictionary

I found myself starting to want something like this:

```Swift
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func get(_ key: Key, backup: Value) -> Value {
        if let stored = self[key] {
            return stored
        } else {
            self[key] = backup
            return backup
        }
    }
}
```

but in my experience, Swift leaves out things like this because it has an alternative (intended) way to do it. I haven't found such a way in documentation. **Did I miss this function, or should I create it?** Also, if they left it out and I shouldn't create it, why?

Comment: Similar solutions here: [Swift Dictionary default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415188/swift-dictionary-default-value).

Comment: You didn't miss out a function :) It's usually a good idea to create an extension or function of some kind (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't have a function like this. It is fine to create an extension in this circumstance.