# Swift dictionary 'else' keyword?

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift. Is there a way to define a dictionary with an 'otherwise' type of method? For example

```
Var dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2, AnythingElse: 3]

dictionary("$")
```

Should return the value 3.

Comment: @Lamar So dictionary should equal  ["a": 1, "b": 2, <any,any>: 3] ?

Comment: @John The [swift3] and [swift3.0.2] tags are only for questions *directly* related to changes in the language for those versions, which this isn't. The [swift] tag is for general language questions, which this is. The [xcode] tag is for questions about the IDE itself, which this is not. For those reasons, I've rolled back your tag edit.

Comment: I think you could do that `var dict = Dictionary<AnyHashable,Int>`

Comment: @vadian I made to correction, I meant to say `AnyHashable` not `Any`

Comment: @Lamar so I need to say Var dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2, <AnyHashable,Int>: 3] ? (Sorry, I'm an ignorant beginner).

Comment: `var dict: Dictionary<AnyHashable,Int> = ["a":1,"b":3,56:4]`

Comment: This kind of *wildcard* is not supported. Dictionaries contain concrete key-value pairs. The key is required to conform to `Hashable`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Dictionary default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415188/swift-dictionary-default-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a default value for when the item isn't there do this:

```
let item = dictionary["key"] ?? defaultValue
```

Now item will be the entry in the dictionary whose key is "key" or defaultValue if there was no entry for "key"

***example***

```
var dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2]
let defaultValue = 3

print(dictionary["a"] ?? defaultValue)
print(dictionary["$"] ?? defaultValue)
```

This will print 1 and 3.

Comment: How do I go about calling the dictionary? (Once again I apologize for the beginner's ignorance)

Comment: @John May I politely urge you to spend lots of quality time reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book from Apple before posting any more questions. Learn at least the basics. SO isn't really a site suited to answering such basic questions (I'm referring to the question in your comment to this answer). Enjoy.

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't mean how to call a dictionary in general. I mean this specific type of dictionary (one with a key)

Comment: @John What do you mean? There's only one type of dictionary and it is a set of key/value pairs. The code in this answer shows you how to simply answer your question using your own `dictionary` variable.

Comment: John please see my updated answer, but I agree with rmaddy that you could probably learn a lot by studying the documentation at the link he provided, it does cover this kind of topic as well as many other useful things.