# mutable collection as a value in swift dictionary are copied and not referenced therefor becoming immutable

Tags: swift, struct, swift4, swift-dictionary

My collections are copied to the dictionary rather than stored as mutable references.

for instance:

```
  var map = Dictionary<Int,Set<Int>>()
  var mySet = map[key, default: Set()]
  if mySet.count == 0 {
    // the collection doesn't exist in the dictionary so I am setting it
    // stored by value and not reference
    sectionToFeed[sectionId] = mapping
  }
  // this doesn't mutate the stored set
  mySet.insert(item)
  print(mySet)    <<<<<<<<<<<< Prints different collections
  print(map[key]) <<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: please post the code which could be represented

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Dictionary default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415188/swift-dictionary-default-value)

Comment: `map[key, default: Set()]` doesn't **set** set default value in the dictionary. It just returns it when the key `key` is not present. See the above url for a way to also have the default value being set

Comment: This is not a question. Please tell us what question you have. I assume it has nothing to do with `default` values.

Comment: `Set`s are value types.  `mySet` is either a copy of `map[key]` or a brand new set.  Either way, it is completely independent of the value in your dictionary.  You'll have to write it back when you're done: `map[key] = mySet`.